# In Roslyn API what the Speculative Semantic Model is?

Tags: roslyn

What does the extension function `SemanticModel.TryGetSpeculativeSemanticModel` return? What is it good for?

I could not find any meaningful documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpextensions.trygetspeculativesemanticmodel?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) for `TryGetSpeculativeSemanticModel` says:

> Get a SemanticModel object that is associated with X that did not appear in this source code. This can be used to get detailed semantic information about sub-parts of X that did not appear in source code.

The [analyzer code](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/ReadabilityRules/SX1101DoNotPrefixLocalMembersWithThis.cs#L67-L69) for the StyleCop [SX1101](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/ed67842090a8e1ce55e6c29aebc799c3e5de5e17/documentation/SX1101.md) diagnostic offers a great example of this API's usage. SX1101 tells you that it's safe to remove a `this.` qualifier from your code.

Lets step through a slightly simplified version of the analyzer code:

```cs
var memberAccessExpression = (MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)ctx.Node.Parent;
var originalSymbolInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(
    memberAccessExpression,
    context.CancellationToken);
var statement = context.Node.FirstAncestorOrSelf<StatementSyntax>();
var annotation = new SyntaxAnnotation();
var speculationRoot = statement.ReplaceNode(
    memberAccessExpression, 
    memberAccessExpression.Name.WithAdditionalAnnotations(annotation));
```

`context.Node` is a `ThisExpressionSyntax`. `speculationRoot` is an expression where we replaced `this.SomeMember` with `SomeMember`. The `annotation` is used for quick lookup later.

Now that we have generated a modified version of the code, we want to check if it would a) still compile, and b) still refer to the same thing. Since the sources in Roslyn are immutable, we'd need to compile the entire project again (which would be doable, but more expensive) to get a new `SemanticModel` for the changed code.

**Here** is where `TryGetSpeculativeSemanticModel` steps in:

```cs
if(!context.SemanticModel.TryGetSpeculativeSemanticModel(
    statement.SpanStart,
    speculationRoot,
    out var speculativeModel)) return;

var mappedNode = speculationRoot.GetAnnotatedNodes(annotation).Single();
var newSymbolInfo = speculativeModel.GetSymbolInfo(mappedNode, context.CancellationToken);
```

So now if we manage to get a speculative semantic model, it means `SomeMember` was valid at that same position in code as `this.SomeMember`. We've used the `annotation` to quickly look up the `SomeMember` syntax node and then get it's semantic info from the `speculativeModel`.

All that's left to do now is to check whether the modified statement means the same thing as the original one.

```cs
if (!Equals(originalSymbolInfo.Symbol, newSymbolInfo.Symbol)) return;
context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Descriptor, context.Node.GetLocation()));
```